# Get registered devices Google Homegraph

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home, google-assist-api, google-smart-home

Is it possible to receive a list with all registered devices, homes and rooms from a Google account with a google actions? 
Basically I want to create an action which allows to send notifications to a specific google home device.

I know that this might somehow involve using the Homegraph API. I thought that request sync might do the job but I didn't get it to work. I don't know how to find out the agentUserID.

Anyone experience with using the homegraph API?

Thank you in advance.
Oli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible to use the API to get a list of devices at the user level. The API only allows one to get the devices per user per action.

It also does not allow one to get the homes and rooms for a Google account.